# Java: Operations with Colors (add, subtract)? - Colors in a constant class

Tags: java, colors, operators, enums, rgb

I'm working with `java.awt.Color` instances. Is there any way to do arithmetic operations on colors? Something like `rgb(20, 20, 20) + rgb(10, 200, 170) = rgb(30, 220, 190)`?

What I'm trying to do: I have a gui that features a table, where if the user clicks on a cell, the other cells change color based on their relationship to the selected one. I'm looking for a way to avoid hard coding what the base colors are, and on which color values they change.

So the selected cell might be `rgb(255, 0, 0)`, and everything else might be between `rgb(0, 0, 0)` and `rgb(0, 255, 0)` based on their values. I'm thinking... enums?

```
import java.awt.Color;

public enum ColorConstant {
    SELECTED (new rgb(255, 0, 0), "Red"),
    MAX_DISTANCE (new rgb(0, 255, 0), "Green")

    private Color shade;
    private ??? whichColorToModify;

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are the methods Color.brighter and Color.darker.

Other than that, I usually write a small utility methods for such purposes, like:

```
private static Color brightness(Color c, double scale) {
    int r = Math.min(255, (int) (c.getRed() * scale));
    int g = Math.min(255, (int) (c.getGreen() * scale));
    int b = Math.min(255, (int) (c.getBlue() * scale));
    return new Color(r,g,b);
}
```

Comment: Dude! Never thought about using Math.min but it sure makes sense! D:

Answer (score 2):

[HSLColor](http://www.camick.com/java/blog.html?name=hsl-color) might be what you are looking for. It allow you to adjust the tone/shade of a color easily.

Comment: `new HslColor(new HslColor(48.0,100.0, 50.0).adjustHue(60.0)).getSaturation()` returns `100.0000002`

And after this any adjusting throws an error Illegal argument saturation out of range. Can u help me??

`new HslColor(new HslColor(48.0,100.0, 50.0).adjustHue(180.0)).getSaturation()` returns 100.0000002

Comment: `new HslColor(48.0, 100.0, 50.0).adjustHue(60.0)` is returning a java.awt.Color that has 1.00001 in Red componant > 1 :(