# Font problems to change

Tags: java, user-interface, fonts

Hi iam trying to do some program that allowed me to change my font color so if i have used a check box but the problem is the combination of the color . can i combine two colors to make it the color of my font ?

```
Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12);
                field.setFont(font);
                field.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);// can i do this Color.YELLOW+GREEN ?
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.*;        

public class Example {
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("HelloColorfulWorld");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12);

        Color yellowColor = new Color(255, 255, 0); // Yellow  
        Color greenColor = new Color(0, 255, 0); // Green

        Color mixColor = mixTwoColors(yellowColor, greenColor); // Yellow + Green

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello, Colorful World!");

        label.setFont(font);
        label.setForeground(mixColor);
        frame.getContentPane().add(label);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static Color mixTwoColors(Color color1, Color color2) {
        double alpha = color1.getAlpha() + color2.getAlpha();

        double weight1 = color1.getAlpha() / alpha;
        double weight2 = color2.getAlpha() / alpha;

        double r = weight1 * color1.getRed() + weight2 * color2.getRed();
        double g = weight1 * color1.getGreen() + weight2 * color2.getGreen();
        double b = weight1 * color1.getBlue() + weight2 * color2.getBlue();

        double a = Math.max(color1.getAlpha(), color2.getAlpha());

        return new Color((int) r, (int) g, (int) b, (int) a);
    }    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

More information about operations with colors you can find there:

- [**RGB color model**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model)
- [Computing the combined color of two colors (Over operator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352124/computing-the-combined-color-of-two-colors-over-operator)
- [Java: Operations with Colors (add, subtract)? - Colors in a constant class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618169/java-operations-with-colors-add-subtract-colors-in-a-constant-class)
- [Convert RGB values into integer pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801366/convert-rgb-values-into-integer-pixel)
- [Set Color as int value for use in setRGB(int x, int y, int rgb) method? — Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708204/set-color-as-int-value-for-use-in-setrgbint-x-int-y-int-rgb-method-java)
- [Algorithm for Additive Color Mixing for RGB Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726549/algorithm-for-additive-color-mixing-for-rgb-values)
- [Calculation of a mixed color in RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255973/calculation-of-a-mixed-color-in-rgb)
- [Mixing two RGB color vectors to get resultant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892020/mixing-two-rgb-color-vectors-to-get-resultant)
- ...

Comment: oh sir how did you do to combine that ? and where did you get the numbers in new colors like (154,205,50); ?